# Xbox 360 ports are blocked

Tags: xbox-360, networking

I have a Xbox 360, and live in a sports center. The owner of the house have blocked the ports that I need to use, when I want to play online with my Xbox.

Is there some way that I can play online?
It is not an option to open the ports in the router.

Comment: Well, is it an option to open the ports ONLY for the IP that the Xbox360 uses?

Comment: @5pike no, the owner wants no game traffic on his network :(, so is it an option to play with other ports?

Comment: This is a question you need to take up with the owner of the network. What's to stop him from blocking other ports if he finds out? And no, you can't change the ports on the Xbox 360. You will need to unblock them or open them on the network. Or switch to a different network. Mobile broadband will in many situations suffice.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Mobile broadband will NOT suffice if you ever want to get updates for your games (which you will if you want to play online).

Comment: That depends entirely on where in the world you are. Here in Norway I can get a mobile broadband account with 40Mbit/sec download speed and a 30GB soft cap per month of data, which would suffice just fine (source: [Telenor Mobilt Bredbånd XL](http://www.telenor.no/privat/mobiltbredband/mobilt-bredband-xl.jsp))